# Directshow capture from avermedia gamer portable C875

Tags: directshow, capture

I have purchased an avermedia Gamer portable C875 capture device and wish to integrate to it using directshow.

I have tried OBS Studio and this captures fine, however when I try any of my own directshow code in c++ builder I can see the device, but I cannot obtain video format or any video feed.

I have tried datastead ffmpeg components, mitov basic video, winsoft wcamera and FFVCL components, all which are directshow compatible and all of which detect the device but cannot preview or capture any video.

I even used straight forward directshow code from @Spektre which is just a basic wrapper for the windows DirectShow API.

This detects but freezes when calling

hr = graph->AddSourceFilterForMoniker(moniker, 0, dev->filtername, &dev->filter);

and dev->filtename = "LGP Stream Engine"

If I take this device out of the list then directshow driver fails on Select of the "Avermedia C875 Capture device"

I contacted avermedia and they say the device is directshow 10 compatible and no new driver work being done as it is EOL.

Any suggestions as to how I can interface to and capture from this device using directshow?  EZCapture works fine, C875 doesn't.

[image: C875 Filters]

[image: EZCapture filters]

Comment: I have AVerMedia Live Gamer Ultra GC553 and it works with DirectShow in the expected way. Specifically, [GraphStudioNext](https://github.com/cplussharp/graph-studio-next) can be set to connect video capture filter to VMR and video is streamed well.

Comment: Also, reliable pieces of software that prove whether device/driver works or not via DirectShow are: SDK GraphEdit, GraphStudioNext (link above, comes with source code), SDK sample AMCap.

Comment: @Roman thanks for that, both devices show up in this application, but C875 doesn't seem to have same pins, I will try and attach some images so you can maybe explain to me what I would need to do

Comment: Have you configured the crossbar? Maybe it uses the wrong video in?

Comment: @CPlusSharp I am not even sure that the graph builder for any of these components adds the crossbar.  Is there any way I can ask my code to investigate the graph actually built by the components?

Comment: On the first picture, the gray box is excessive, you can delete it. right click orange's Virtual Video Out and choose Render to add video renderer filter and connect it. If succeeded, press Play button (or menu command) to start streaming. When everything is fine video is shown in popup window. These are steps to confirm the device works in first place before going to writing code. If this orange filter is not functioning right, your code would just replicate this behavior.

Comment: @Roman If I select the Virtual Video out Pin and then click render pin I get E_NOINTERFACE

Comment: You are describing the unexpected behavior. It's hard to say why it happens this way: broken installation, outdated driver or anything else. If OBS is working work you maybe the best would be to grab their source code and put breakpoints on relevant lines to see what they are doing. Maybe it's something specific to this hardware as it supposedly targets OBS-like streaming specifically.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the avermedia C875 is not compatible with writing direct to an AVI capture or video render.  As it is an obsolete product avermedia are not interested in providing a more compliant directshow driver.

Avermedia gamer lite portable 2 plus, is directshow compliant and does render as well as save to AVI.

I am not sure what OBS does that is different, the project is a bit too complex for me to try and extract just the video recording section to see how it handles things differently.

Thanks for the feedback @Roman, helped me track things down.